# How to find the mode when none of the terms repeat?

Tags: statistics

What is the mode of a series / distribution of values when none of the values of the distribution are repeated , for example :
What is the mode of 1 , 3 , 45, 67 , 89 , 100

Comment: Google doesn't know the answer of this ?

Comment: They're *all* the mode (it's multimodal). And, wrong site, you want *mathematics.stackexchange*...